# Find the errors in userscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I uploaded a `user script` to the `openuserjs`. 
It says;

```
to many errors, %88 scanned.
```

How can I get the details of the errors? There is no sign of error or underline in the editor of openuserjs.

When I enable script in the browser, it gives me errors as;

```
VM91 sd_1608R3.js:207 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).addEllipsis is not a functionbuildArticleList @ VM91 sd_1608R3.js:207getArticleList @ VM91 sd_1608R3.js:188n @ VM90 sdX_1608R3.js:70fireWith @ VM90 sdX_1608R3.js:71b @ VM90 sdX_1608R3.js:164c @ VM90 sdX_1608R3.js:177
VM91 sd_1608R3.js:457 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).outline is not a function
```

When I clicked the error, it navigates me to the minified version of jquery. I did not found these errors userful for me. I couldn't find the exact errors.

So how can I get the errors of userscript that include jquery?

Comment: addEliipsis and outline are not methods of pure jQuery. Sounds like maybe you are missing a reference to another library?

Comment: How can I specify which library I need? They're methods of which library? When I search as addEliipsis library couldn't get any valuable results.

Comment: I've no idea, it's your code! I assumed you knew what methods you were trying to call and why :-) .

Comment: But I just get the text fields in some websites. Just bunch of `if else` cases and parsing text fields according to the domains. such as; `$('.title-with-crossmark').text()` just all.

Comment: does it work without errors if you just include your script in a normal html page (without uploading to openuserjs or using any other tools)?

Comment: yes it doesn't alert any errors but in console as I wrote in the question, it gives that kind of errors.

Comment: ok well maybe you need to post the entire thing then it might be possible to see if there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: ok I will add my code